# make my macro don't duplicate results

Tags: vba, excel

When I run my code more than one time it will duplicate results in sheets. I need  to remove the previous data and paste the new data every time I run it.

```
Sub CreateMonthlySheets()
    Dim lastRow, mMonth, tstDate1, tstDate2, shtName, nxtRow

    On Error Resume Next
    'Turn off ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'Make a copy of the data sheet and sort by date
    Sheets("Main Data Sheet").Copy After:=Sheets(1)
    Sheets(2).Name = "SortTemp"
    With Sheets("SortTemp")
        lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Rows("2:" & lastRow).Sort Key1:=Range("C2"), Order1:=xlAscending

        'Using SortTemp Sheet, create monthly sheets by
        'testing Month and Year values in Column A

        'Loop through dates
        For Each mMonth In .Range("C2:C" & lastRow)
            tstDate1 = Month(mMonth) & Year(mMonth)
            tstDate2 = Month(mMonth.Offset(-1, 0)) & Year(mMonth.Offset(-1, 0))

            'If Month and Year are different than cell above, create new sheet
            If tstDate1 <> tstDate2 Then
                ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)


                'Name the sheet based on the Month and Year
                ActiveSheet.Name = MonthName(Month(mMonth)) & " " & Year(mMonth)
                'Copy Column Widths and Header Row
                .Rows(1).Copy
                ActiveSheet.Rows(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8    'ColumnWidth
                ActiveSheet.Rows(1).PasteSpecial      'Data and Formats
            End If
        Next
        On Error GoTo 0

        'Loop through dates, copying row to the correct sheet
        For Each mMonth In .Range("C2:C" & lastRow)
            'Create sheetname variable
            shtName = MonthName(Month(mMonth)) & " " & Year(mMonth)
            'Determine next empty row in sheet
            nxtRow = Sheets(shtName).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            'Copy Data
            .Range(mMonth.Address).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets(shtName).Cells(nxtRow, 1)
        Next
    End With
    'Delete SortTemp sheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("SortTemp").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    'Turn on ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide an example of the data

Comment: i have main sheet with data one of rows has dates (1/1/2016,13/2/2016,17/6/2016)my code create sheets for each month. when i run my code it will work fine creates sheets with month names and each sheet contain data in this month but when i run it again it will duplicate the data in created sheets and create another range of sheets . what i want is(if sheets exist firstly delete all data in sheets that exist and after that move data to sheets  )

Comment: you say _"rows has dates"_ but your code loops through a column... I assumed dates are in column "C" of "Main Data Sheet" and pasted into "SortTemp" as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found The Solution>>thanks For all

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateMonthlySheets()
    Dim mMonth As Range
    Dim shtName As String
    Dim monthSht As Worksheet
    Dim newSheet As Boolean


'    'Turn off ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'Make a copy of the data sheet and sort by date

    With GetSheet("SortTemp", True, newSheet) '<-- get your "temp" sheet: if not existent then create it
        If Not newSheet Then .Cells.Clear '<--| if it existed then clear it
        Sheets("Main Data Sheet").UsedRange.Copy Destination:=.Cells(1, 1) '<--| fill it with "Main Data Sheet" sheet

        'Using SortTemp Sheet, create monthly sheets by
        'testing Month and Year values in Column A

        'Loop through dates
      For Each mMonth In .Range("C2:C" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
            shtName = MonthName(Month(mMonth)) & Year(mMonth) '<--| build "month" sheet name
            Set monthSht = GetSheet(shtName, False, newSheet) 'Set "month" sheet: if not existent then create it
            monthSht.UsedRange.Offset(1).Clear

        Next


        For Each mMonth In .Range("C2:C" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
            shtName = MonthName(Month(mMonth)) & Year(mMonth) '<--| build "month" sheet name
            Set monthSht = GetSheet(shtName, False, newSheet) 'Set "month" sheet: if not existent then create it
           ' monthSht.UsedRange.Offset(1).Clear
          '  If newSheet Then '<--| if it didn't exist...
                '...Copy Column Widths and Header Row
                .Rows(1).Copy
                monthSht.Rows(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8 'ColumnWidth
                monthSht.Rows(1).PasteSpecial          'Data and Formats
         '   Else 'otherwise...
                'monthSht.UsedRange.Offset(1).Clear '<--| ...clear it from row 2 downwards (assuming row 1 has at least one value...)
         '   End If
            'Copy Data
            mMonth.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=monthSht.Cells(monthSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        Next

    End With
    'Delete SortTemp sheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("SortTemp").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    'Turn on ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Function GetSheet(shtName As String, Optional okClear As Boolean = False, Optional newSheet As Boolean = False) As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetSheet = Worksheets(shtName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If GetSheet Is Nothing Then
        newSheet = True
        Set GetSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
        GetSheet.Name = shtName
    Else
        If okClear Then GetSheet.Cells.Clear
        newSheet = False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: you took my answer, posted it and marked as your solution? Please, get things back fair! Thank you

Comment: it'd be nice of you to give proper feedbacks to people trying and help you

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateMonthlySheets()
    Dim mMonth As Range
    Dim shtName As String
    Dim monthSht As Worksheet
    Dim newSheet As Boolean

'    'Turn off ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'Make a copy of the data sheet and sort by date
    With GetSheet("SortTemp", True, newSheet) '<-- get your "temp" sheet: if not existent then create it
        If Not newSheet Then .Cells.Clear '<--| if it existed then clear it
        Sheets("Main Data Sheet").UsedRange.Copy Destination:=.Cells(1, 1) '<--| fill it with "Main Data Sheet" sheet

        'Using SortTemp Sheet, create monthly sheets by
        'testing Month and Year values in Column A

        'Loop through dates
        For Each mMonth In .Range("C2:C" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row)
            shtName = MonthName(Month(mMonth)) & " " & Year(mMonth) '<--| build "month" sheet name
            Set monthSht = GetSheet(shtName, False, newSheet) 'Set "month" sheet: if not existent then create it
            If newSheet Then '<--| if it didn't exist...
                '...Copy Column Widths and Header Row
                .Rows(1).Copy
                monthSht.Rows(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8 'ColumnWidth
                monthSht.Rows(1).PasteSpecial          'Data and Formats
            Else 'otherwise...
                monthSht.UsedRange.Offset(1).Clear '<--| ...clear it from row 2 downwards (assuming row 1 has at least one value...)
            End If
            'Copy Data
            mMonth.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=monthSht.Cells(monthSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        Next

    End With
    'Delete SortTemp sheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("SortTemp").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    'Turn on ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

'Sub main()
'    Dim sh As Worksheet
'    Dim existent As Boolean
'
'    Set sh = GetSheet("data1", False, existent)
'
'End Sub

Function GetSheet(shtName As String, Optional okClear As Boolean = False, Optional newSheet As Boolean = False) As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetSheet = Worksheets(shtName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If GetSheet Is Nothing Then
        newSheet = True
        Set GetSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
        GetSheet.Name = shtName
    Else
        If okClear Then GetSheet.Cells.Clear
        newSheet = False
    End If
End Function
```

which results from:

- avoid `On Error Resume Next` ruling for more than strictly needed
- no need to loop twice

Comment: Dear @user3598756 , my code create range of sheets with month manes when i run your code it will give me error in this code `monthSht.Range(.Rows(2), .Rows(Rows.Count)).Delete '<--| ...clear it from row 2 downwards...`

Comment: change `.Delete` into `Clear` (see edited answer). If it errors out again please specify what kind of error it is

Comment: see edited code where I also changed the statement copying rows from "SortTemp" sheet into "month" sheet

Comment: @Daniel: did you get through it?

Comment: it's work very good but there are one problem it give me one record in one month example (i have many rows in January its give me only the last row of data  ).. thank you for your support

Comment: there is no error in code . but when i run it it will copy only last row of data of months (there are many rows in every month it must be copy all rows of data to their month sheet)

Comment: so step through the code and see what's happening line by line

Comment: i did it but i didn't able to fix it that's why i asked you . thank you in advance for my support

Comment: sorry, what did you ask me?

Comment: i know you helped me but i am really can't fix this . so please can you help me ?

Comment: as I said, you can post a minimal example reproducing the error

Comment: dear sir i have only this problem . when i run the code the result correct but in each month i have many records , i want to copy all rows of data to the sheet but my code only copy last row of data